# SSH with Dropbear: "Permission denied (publickey)"

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-keys, rsa, dropbear

I've create a RSA key pair with `ssh-keygen`. In `/etc/dropbear-initramfs/authorized_keys` I have the public key, and on my client machine I have the keypair in the `/home/<name>/.ssh/` directory. After running `update-initramfs -u`, I still am not able to connect with Dropbear.

Here is how I have it set up on the server:

`/etc/dropbear-initramfs/authorized_keys`:

```
ssh-rsa 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 root@ubuntu
```

`ls -la /etc/dropbear-initramfs` shows:

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Apr 17 23:11 .
drwxr-xr-x 99 root root 4096 Apr 17 21:33 ..
-rw-------  1 root root  565 Apr 17 23:11 authorized_keys
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  579 Apr 17 22:48 config
-rw-------  1 root root  458 Apr 17 21:33 dropbear_dss_host_key
-rw-------  1 root root  140 Apr 17 21:33 dropbear_ecdsa_host_key
-rw-------  1 root root  805 Apr 17 21:33 dropbear_rsa_host_key
-rw-------  1 root root 2590 Apr 17 23:11 id_rsa
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  565 Apr 17 23:11 id_rsa.pub
```

After seeing "Begin: Starting dropbear ..." on my server, and then running the following command on my client machine from a different network: `ssh -o "HostKeyAlgorithms ssh-rsa" -p <port> root@<ip> -vvv`, I get the following output:

```
OpenSSH_8.8p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1m  14 Dec 2021
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname <ip> is address
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/home/<name>/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/home/<name>/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to <ip> [<ip>] port <port>.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x48
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/<name>/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /home/<name>/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/<name>/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/<name>/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/<name>/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/<name>/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/<name>/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/<name>/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/<name>/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/<name>/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/<name>/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/<name>/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/<name>/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/<name>/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.8
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version dropbear_2019.78
debug1: compat_banner: no match: dropbear_2019.78
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to <ip>:<port> as 'root'
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,kexguess2@matt.ucc.asn.au
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha1-96,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha1-96,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256
debug2: compression ctos: zlib@openssh.com,none
debug2: compression stoc: zlib@openssh.com,none
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:k5mkg88bVoGfNcqRVQ4dO+A3bUDOsVvKH7QBLuUud5A
debug3: put_host_port: [<ip>]:<port>
debug3: put_host_port: [<ip>]:<port>
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /home/<name>/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys_file: loaded 1 keys from [<ip>]:<port>
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/<name>/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host '[<ip>]:<port>' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/<name>/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/<name>/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:uibL6T72PUCtFFh9FUMwgvTng4YjrQyoR1pido1PKa8
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/<name>/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/<name>/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/<name>/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/<name>/.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/<name>/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/<name>/.ssh/id_xmss 
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/<name>/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:uibL6T72PUCtFFh9FUMwgvTng4YjrQyoR1pido1PKa8
debug1: send_pubkey_test: no mutual signature algorithm
debug1: Trying private key: /home/<name>/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/<name>/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/<name>/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/<name>/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/<name>/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug3: no such identity: /home/<name>/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/<name>/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /home/<name>/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/<name>/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug3: no such identity: /home/<name>/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/<name>/.ssh/id_xmss
debug3: no such identity: /home/<name>/.ssh/id_xmss: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
root@<ip>: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Been struggling with this for a while now...

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The SSH client is OpenSSH 8.8. [Its release notes](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-8.8) tell:

> ### Potentially-incompatible changes
>
> This release disables RSA signatures using the SHA-1 hash algorithm
> by default.
> [...]
> Incompatibility is more likely when connecting to older SSH
> implementations that have not been upgraded or have not closely
> tracked improvements in the SSH protocol.
> [...]
> For example, the following stanza in `~/.ssh/config` will enable
> RSA/SHA1 for host and user authentication for a single destination
> host:
>
> ```
> Host old-host
>     HostkeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
>     PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
> ```

or its equivalent command line option (actually only the 2nd entry should be needed for this case):

```
ssh -o PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa ...
```

which should prevent this to happen:

> ```
> debug1: send_pubkey_test: no mutual signature algorithm
> ```

Reproduced failing and fixed with *Dropbear* version 2018.76 (and tested not needed with 2020.81). OP's 2019.78 isn't good enough either. *Dropbear*'s documentation tells the required adjustment was done after version [2020.79](https://github.com/mkj/dropbear/blob/DROPBEAR_2020.79/CHANGES#L9):

> - **Support using rsa-sha2 signatures**. No changes are needed to hostkeys/authorized_keys entries, existing RSA keys can be used with
>   the new signature format (signatures are ephemeral within a session).
>   **Old ssh-rsa signatures will no longer be supported by OpenSSH in
>   future so upgrading is recommended**.

Switching to a non-RSA private/public key pair (and updating `authorized_keys`) should also be an alternative to lowering client's default security settings or to upgrading *Dropbear*, but again, one must ensure compatible choices are used.

Comment: So I created an unencrypted ecdsa key pair, and that seemed to have fixed it. Hopefully this is still kinda secure. Thanks!

Comment: I hope you did also see in my answer that you picked the wrong of the two options: `ssh -o "HostKeyAlgorithms ssh-rsa"` (won't work) instead of `ssh -o PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa` (will work with current keys).

Comment: I understood it, based on your last paragraph, that switching to a different key type would be better to not have to "lower clients default security settings (...)"? Is using ecdsa a good solution?

Comment: should be: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/50878/ecdsa-vs-ecdh-vs-ed25519-vs-curve25519

Comment: I'd started to have this issue after Updating to MacOS Ventura 13.0 at my laptop. It has bundled OpenSSH 9.0